# VBA, MS Access - Set text box to query

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, querying

I have a form, a combobox (dropdown menu) and a textbox.

When a specific value from the combobox is chosen, I want the textbox to query for values in a table.

This is my idea, but it's not working:

```
Private Sub Combobox1_Click()
If Me.Combobox1.Value = "London" Then

    Dim SQL As String

    SQL = "SELECT tabel_prices.[London]" _
        & "FROM tabel_prices "

    Me.TextBox1.Value = SQL

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you want to do, this will just put the SQL in the textbox.  A bit more is needed for the results if that's what you are after?  Also, it's on the click event, not the change event, not sure if that is intentional.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I want to query for the prices that are located within column "London", which is found in the table "table_prices". The textbox should list all prices found in the column.

I think I need to set the Control Source, but this doesn't work either: `Me.TextBox1.ControlSource = Me.[London].Value´ (results in `#Name?`).

The reason it is onclick is that you need to click on an item on a dropdown menu before I want the values to be shown - dont know if I am using it how its intended?

Comment: Should use AfterUpdate event of Combobox1. Then you also really need a 'cascading' combobox to hold the related prices http://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/Forms/combo-boxes/cascading.html

Comment: You could look at building the sql like so `SQL = "SELECT table_prices.[" & me.combobox1.value & "]" 
        & " FROM tabel_prices "` also.  Maybe a listbox would also help, with the SQL set and then use the combobox and `.requery` ?

Comment: If you have a field for each city, then table_prices is not normalized. Do you really have table spelled as tabel?

Comment: @June7 Yes, the spelling is not the problem, although grammar is not correct. I like your idea of cascading combobox, which I might have to go with. The problem is that there is already a current design in which they use textboxes, so management prioritize if I can fit a solution with my first proposed approach. Thanks for the advice still. The table of cities were something I came up with as an example and not the actual data I am working with

Comment: Okay, textbox can be filled with prices by iterating recordset in a VBA loop block and concatenating the values. However, the result is just a string of characters, not a list of selectable items. Is that what you want? Review http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html

Comment: @June7 It might be it. I will definitely try it out. Otherwise, I will use the cascading combo boxes, which it feels like I am getting more keen on. So either way, I will probably use one of your solutions. I appreciate the help a lot, so thank you :)